# PyQt5 - Problem updating TableView with new pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5

I have `PyQt5` App which generates pandas dataframe to PyQt `TableView`.Dataframe is generated with function getPageInfo which is calling class which generates pandas dataframe object.

Everything works nicely for default value of `QLineEdit()` which is URL entry for class `getPageInfo`  that generates pandas dataframe based on URL input.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
                             QMainWindow, QGridLayout)

from getURLPage import GetPage
from getPandas import PandasTableModel

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.setText("https://www.samplesite.com/")

        self.getdata = QPushButton()
        self.getdata.setText("Show data")

        self.getdata.clicked.connect(self.getPageInfo)
        self.pdtable = QTableView()
        self.model = PandasTableModel(self.getPageInfo())
        self.pdtable.setModel(self.model)
        self.pdtable.resize(800, 600)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.le, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.getdata, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pdtable, 1, 0, 1, 0)

    def getPageInfo(self):
        self.siteURL = self.le.text()
        getPage = GetPage(self.siteURL,
                          "data",
                          "page")
        pageDF = getPage.getAdInfo()
        return pageDF


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    box = App()
    box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It displays nicely searchbar, push button and pandas dataframe which is generated based on default input for `QLineEdit()` which in this case is `"https://www.samplesite.com/"`.

This URL is input for `getPageInfo` function which returns PandasDataframe.
It works also for any other default input.
Problem is that it's not working if user enters same url in `QLineEdit()` and pushes `QPushButton()`.

Function actually gets new DataFrame for user-given URL entry but it's not displayed in `QTableView()`

**EDIT:**

I've moved generation of `self.model` to `getPageInfo` function but now I have error:

> ```
>  self.pdtable.setModel(self.model)
> AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'model'
> ```

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
                             QMainWindow, QGridLayout)

from getURLPage import GetPage
from getPandas import PandasTableModel


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.setText("https://www.samplesite.com/")

        self.getdata = QPushButton()
        self.getdata.setText("Show data")
        self.getdata.clicked.connect(self.getPageInfo)
        self.pdtable = QTableView()
        self.pdtable.setModel(self.model)
        self.pdtable.resize(800, 600)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.le, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.getdata, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pdtable, 1, 0, 1, 0)

    def getPageInfo(self):
        self.siteURL = self.le.text()
        getPage = GetPage(self.siteURL,
                          "data",
                          "page")
        pageDF = getPage.getAdInfo()
        self.model = PandasTableModel(pageDF)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    box = App()
    box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When a slot is executed when a signal is triggered, the return value of the slot is ignored. This means that in order for anything to happen you need to update the `self.model` with the new dataframe inside `getPageInfo` instead of returning the dataframe.

Comment: @Heike , I did that but than I have `AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'model'`. - please see my edit.

Comment: You need to call `self.getPageInfo` at least once before the line `self.pdtable.setModel(self.model)` in `__init__`. Otherwise `self.model` is still undefined. Also, since you are redefining `self.model` rather than updating the dataframe in `self.model`, you also need to reset the model of `self.pdtable `in `self.getPageInfo`, otherwise the table view will continue using the old model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is working solution.**
@Heike - thank you for tip!

pandas data model (`self.model`) and `QTableView()` as well both needs to be updated inside function.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
                             QMainWindow, QGridLayout)

from getURLPage import GetPage
from getPandas import PandasTableModel

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.le.setText("https://www.samplesite.com/")

        self.getdata = QPushButton()
        self.getdata.setText("Show data")

        self.getdata.clicked.connect(self.getPageInfo)
        self.pdtable = QTableView()
        self.pdtable.resize(800, 600)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.le, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.getdata, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pdtable, 1, 0, 1, 0)

    def getPageInfo(self):
        self.siteURL = self.le.text()
        getPage = GetPage(self.siteURL,
                          "data",
                          "page")
        pageDF = getPage.getAdInfo()
        self.model = PandasTableModel(pageDF)
        self.pdtable.setModel(self.model)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    box = App()
    box.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```